# ServletContext in Spring MVC application under Jetty

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I try to create Spring MVC application that uses Jetty as servlet container. Feature of my approach is running Jetty inside Spring via bean:

```
<bean id="server" class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server" destroy-method="stop">

    <property name="connectors">
        <list>
            <bean id="connector" class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <property name="port" value="9080" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="handlers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="basicContext" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="basicContext" class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context">
    <property name="contextPath" value="/" />

    <property name="servletHandler">
        <bean class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler">
            <property name="servlets">
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder">
                        <property name="name" value="spring-mvc" />
                        <property name="servlet">
                            <bean class="name.krestjaninoff.hello.util.DispatcherServletWrapper" />
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>

            <property name="servletMappings">
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletMapping">
                        <property name="servletName" value="spring-mvc" />
                        <property name="pathSpec" value="/*" />
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>
```

To pass application context to my servlet I use simple wrapper for DispatcherServlet that implements ContextAware interface:

```
public class DispatcherServletWrapper extends DispatcherServlet implements
        ApplicationContextAware {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5870408422415688046L;

    private ApplicationContext appContext;
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext arg0)
            throws BeansException {
        this.appContext = arg0;
    }

    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createWebApplicationContext(
            WebApplicationContext arg0) throws BeansException {

        GenericWebApplicationContext wac = new GenericWebApplicationContext();
        wac.setParent(appContext);
        wac.refresh();

        return wac;
    }
}
```

Application starts well but when I try to get some page I get next exception:

```
2010-12-08 09:50:22,684 [29071401@qtp-4084687-0] DEBUG name.krestjaninoff.hello.util.DispatcherServletWrapper
 - org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:671)
 - Could not complete request
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.getServletContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.exposeHelpers(JstlView.java:135)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:211)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

So, problem occures in JstlView class when it tries get ServletContext. JstlView implements ServletContextAware interface, hence he must know about ServletContext.

In my opinion the problem lies in the fact that ServletContext instance is not created. Can anybody help me?

Comment: my first question would be asking you to explain why you want to start up jetty this way. There are much easier ways, such as with the maven-jetty-plugin.

Comment: Did you find an answer already? What Hans said was actually what I was going to suggest. You're tying your servlet container to your code, which can't be such a good idea.

Comment: I understood that my idea was stupid :) Now my application directly runs Jetty with context that contains Spring MVC servlet.